Query Get Sum of Record Based on Criteria
I'm having a task to create the query function for stock management application.
I have created query where it will generated temporaryTable like this:
(More or less this is user's input desired item and range)



idItem
previousDate
latestDate
company




10
2023-01-03
2023-04-01
A


15
2023-04-01
2023-06-01
A



And I have table to store the transaction in tableTransaction, like this:



idItem
qty
lastQty
transactionDate
company




10
0
10
2023-01-01
A


10
10
10
2023-03-04
A


10
-5
5
2023-03-05
A


10
100
105
2023-03-06
A


15
0
0
2023-01-01
A


15
100
100
2023-03-01
A


15
35
135
2023-04-02
A


15
-15
120
2023-05-01
A


0
100
100
2023-03-01
B


0
-25
75
2023-03-02
B



Would like to ask how do I get as this desired result?
Get the lastQty of previousDate as beginningBalance and lastQty of latestDate as endingBalance; totalInput; totalOutput for each idItem in tableTranscation between previousDate and latestDate (criteria based on previous temporaryTable).
Desired result:



company
idItem
beginningBalance per previousDate
previousDate
endingBalance per latestDate
endingBalance
totalInput
totalOutput




A
10
10
2023-01-03
105
2023-04-01
110
5


A
15
100
2023-04-01
120
2023-06-01
35
15



Thank you for your time, and I'm open to any changes in the design of database. Cheers.

Can you explain what is the logic to calculate totalInput and totalOutput?

totalInput will sum the positive qty of each idItem where the date between previousDate and latestDate. For the totalOutput, same logic but only sum the negative qty

You need to calculate the balance by date as well as the total input, total output separately and join them together.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temporaryTable

CREATE TABLE #temporaryTable (
idItem int,
previousDate date,
latestDate date
);

INSERT INTO #temporaryTable (idItem, previousDate, latestDate)
VALUES
('10','2023-01-03','2023-04-01')
,('15','2023-04-01','2023-06-01')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tableTransaction

CREATE TABLE #tableTransaction (
idItem int,
qty int,
lastQty int,
transactionDate date
);

INSERT INTO #tableTransaction (idItem, qty, lastQty, transactionDate)
VALUES
('10','0','10','2023-01-01')
,('10','10','10','2023-03-04')
,('10','-5','5','2023-03-05')
,('10','100','105','2023-03-06')
,('15','0','0','2023-01-01')
,('15','100','100','2023-03-01')
,('15','35','135','2023-04-02')
,('15','-15','120','2023-05-01')

; WITH beginningBalancePerDate AS (
SELECT temporaryTable.idItem, a.previousDate, tableTransaction.lastQty BalancePerDate
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY temporaryTable.idItem, a.previousDate  ORDER BY tableTransaction.transactionDate desc ) RowNumber
FROM #tableTransaction tableTransaction
  inner join #temporaryTable temporaryTable
    on tableTransaction.idItem = temporaryTable.idItem
  cross apply (
    SELECT temporaryTable.previousDate 
    UNION 
    SELECT temporaryTable.latestDate
  ) a
  WHERE tableTransaction.transactionDate <= a.previousDate
), sumInput AS (
SELECT temporaryTable.idItem, temporaryTable.previousDate, temporaryTable.latestDate,
SUM(CASE WHEN tableTransaction.qty > 0 THEN tableTransaction.qty ELSE 0 END ) totalInput,
SUM(CASE WHEN tableTransaction.qty < 0 THEN tableTransaction.qty * (-1) ELSE 0 END ) totalOutput
FROM #tableTransaction tableTransaction
  inner join #temporaryTable temporaryTable
    on tableTransaction.idItem = temporaryTable.idItem
WHERE tableTransaction.transactionDate <= temporaryTable.latestDate
AND tableTransaction.transactionDate > temporaryTable.previousDate
GROUP BY temporaryTable.idItem, temporaryTable.previousDate, temporaryTable.latestDate
)
SELECT temporaryTable.idItem
, preDate.BalancePerDate beginningBalanceperPreviousDate
, temporaryTable.previousDate
, nextDate.BalancePerDate beginningBalanceperLatestDate
, temporaryTable.latestDate endingBalance -- strange column name
, sumInput.totalInput
, sumInput.totalOutput
FROM  #temporaryTable temporaryTable
  LEFT JOIN sumInput
    ON temporaryTable.idItem = sumInput.idItem
    AND temporaryTable.previousDate = sumInput.previousDate
    AND temporaryTable.latestDate = sumInput.latestDate
  LEFT JOIN beginningBalancePerDate preDate
    ON temporaryTable.idItem = preDate.idItem
    AND temporaryTable.previousDate = preDate.previousDate
    AND preDate.RowNumber = 1
  LEFT JOIN beginningBalancePerDate nextDate
    ON temporaryTable.idItem = nextDate.idItem
    AND temporaryTable.latestDate = nextDate.previousDate
    AND nextDate.RowNumber = 1


Thanks for your help! Furthermore, how to only get the calculation within same company? Will try to edit the question to explain further.
